# why {if row exist then fetch them} does not work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch

I want to check **{if row exist}** first and then `fetch` the results. here is my code:

```
$id = 102;

// connecting to database here
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?');
       $sth->execute(array($id));
       $num_rows = $sth->fetchColumn();

  // if exist
  if($num_rows){

       // then fetch
       while($end = $sth->fetch())
       {
           echo $end['id'];
       }

  }
```

But the output is blank, Why ?

It should be noted that the row with `id = 102` is exist in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO also have similar method [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) but that would return effected rows in some cases.

Quoting from PHP Manual

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
>   PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

As suggested, you can query, count and proceed

```
$id = 102;

// connecting to database here
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE id = ?');
       $sth->execute(array($id));
       $num_rows = $sth->fetchColumn();

// if exist
if($num_rows > 0){

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?');
  $sth->execute(array($id));

    // then fetch
    while($end = $sth->fetch())
    {
         echo $end['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sajad 2 queries for one select? ;))) And with COUNT()? I think it is not good way.

Comment: @Sajad for what? If you can do this with 1 query.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you have only one row with this ID. You can use fetch():

```
$id = 102;

// connecting to database here
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$sth->execute(array($id));
$row = $sth->fetch();

// if record exist
if ($row) {
     var_dump($row);
     die();
}
```

Comment: your mean is should I check existing with `fetch()` instead of `fetchColumn()` ?

Comment: @Sajad thanks. If you have many rows with the same value you can use fetchAll(): $rows = $sth->fetchAll(); if (count($rows) > 0) { //here your code... }